# Trying to generate a HTML table (leaderboards) using PHP + MySQL, it's not displaying anything

Tags: php

I am trying to create a leaderboards table using PHP + MySQL but it isn't displaying anything, here is my code:

It will not show anything though, this is what happens:

If I add more enteries to the database, more rows will appear but they are empty, as can be seen here:

Comment: What's the result of var_dump($row)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant inside the while loop.

Comment: Have you tried to make a query without any html on the script ?

Comment: In that case Chris Hepner's answer is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using capitalized column names in the SQL query and lowercase names in the result object:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE Username = '$user' ORDER BY $sort LIMIT $offset,$count 

...

$row->username
```

If you are on a UNIX-based system, the column names are [case-sensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). Try making these consistent with how the columns are capitalized in the database schema.

Comment: They start with caps in the databse, I will try changing it though, thanks!

Comment: If this is the case, enabling error messages would have flagged this up to you. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: That was the problem, very small mistake and I never even noticed it. Thanks!

Comment: @user898951 Sorry, I wasn't clear on my original reply. It doesn't matter if they're capitalized in the database or not, but they need to be consistent. If you keep the database schema and query the same, just access the result with `$row-.Username`, etc. Lowercase column names are conventional, but not required.

[ Edit: Great, glad it helped. :) ]

Comment: Yeh, I see that now, have gone through everything and changed it, thanks again :)